# how to create a new object from an existing object's constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
if (oo instanceof MyType) {
    var newObj = new oo.constructor;

    // suppose the following check should be ok but it is not
    // newObj should have same constructor as its original oo.

    if (newObj instanceof MyType) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I can't reach "do something". What's wrong?

Comment: oo.constr **a** ctor() ?

Comment: I changed `constrActor` to `constrUctor` and its ok.

Comment: I think he meant constrictor...

Comment: Instead of having to ask if anything is wrong, get familiar with your browser developer tools. Load your page in Chrome and open the developer tools (typically F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I depending on your OS). Now reload your page or do whatever is needed to reach the code in question. It will show you the error in the developer tools window. Here is [information about the Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 3):

Well, just because you might not read the comments, you have a typo in `constructor` (it says `constractor`).

This works:

```
function MyType() {}
oo = new MyType();

if(oo instanceof MyType)
   {
       var newObj = new oo.constructor(); // The mistake was in this line

       if( newObj instanceof MyType)
       {
           console.log("a contractor was killed by a constrictor while constructing");
       }
   }
```

Comment: typo doesn't exist post question edit :S